# Is there a NodeJS-based fulltext search indexer (like Lucene) that works with CouchDB?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-lucene

Is there a NodeJS-based fulltext search engine (like Lucene) that works with CouchDB?

I know there is a Lucene integration, but I would like to use a solution that doesn't require Java, since my deployment environment is a small embedded-device server.

Comment: You're wanting to run a full DB and a full text search engine on the same device and you're worried about the overhead of the JVM?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what I am talking about, but it might be worth trying [FullProof](https://github.com/reyesr/fullproof).